# Twython: How to like photos and follow profiles in the following code

Tags: python, twitter, bots, twython

How would you insert the ability to like the posts re-tweeted, along with follow the users that posted.

```
naughty_words = [" -RT"]
good_words = ["CSGO", "skins", "csgo giveaway" "csgogiveaway",      "CSGOGiveaway", "Giveaway"]
filter = " OR ".join(good_words)
blacklist = " -".join(naughty_words)
keywords = filter + blacklist

twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

search_results = twitter.search(q=keywords, count=20)
try:
    for tweet in search_results["statuses"]:
        try:
            twitter.retweet(id = tweet["id_str"])

        except TwythonError as e:
            "print e"
except TwythonError as e:
    "print e"
```

Answer (score 1):

To ***like* a tweet** when you know its id, use:

```
twitter.create_favorite(id=tweet_id)
```

To **follow the user** that **tweeted the tweet**:

```
tweet = twitter.show_status(id=tweet_id)
twitter.create_friendship(user_id=tweet['user']['id'])
```

**EDIT:**
You can follow the user in one line if you wish, by replacing 'tweet' with the code we used to retrieve the tweet. I've tested it and it does work:

```
twitter.create_friendship(user_id=twitter.show_status(id=tweet_id)['user']['id'])
```